# Show choices of option in -h. When using and optional command line argument in python with argparse

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-arguments, argparse, args

So I want to start my program with an optional argument which has pre-defined choices where the options show up in the -h screen. So that a user knows which option are available for selection.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="This is a program which creates a prediction model for the boston housing dataset.")

parser.add_argument("Model", help="Choose which model you want to use for prediction.",
type=str, choices=["linear_regression", "polynomial_regression"])

parser.add_argument("--fd", metavar="FEEDBACK", help="Set how much feedback you want.",
type=str, choices=["full", "immediate", "weak"])

args = parser.parse_args()
```

The problem is when I start the program with -h I don't see the available choices for --fd. How can I change that so that the user can see the available choices for --fd like with the Model choices shown in the picture?

[image]

Comment: Metavar is how you display the help. What happens if you have `choices` but omit `metavar`? In positional arguments it displayed the choices, so maybe it will work as well? [I haven't used `choices` nor `metavar` myself, I'm more of a flag arguments kind of person, that's why it's a suggestion, not a definite answer.]

Comment: yeah you're right thank you very much. It's a litle bit a shame to omit `metavar` for it.

Comment: Try adding `%(choices)` to the help line.  As your `positional` shows, `choices` can be displayed, both in usage and help.  `metavar` is used to override the default behavior - in both places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like [h4z3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11516012/h4z3) stated in the comments. You need to leave `metavar`out.
Like [hpaulj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/901925/hpaulj) stated in the comments You can also do `%(choices)` in the help line. But For me I needed to leave `%(default)` out. Seems like you can only have one of them in the helper line.